# Speed of Insert

Tags: sql-server

this is a newbe question.

I have two tables in a SQL data base. Both simply a dozen columns of string, int or date, no indexes, no stored procedures. In a `select * from` statement I get ~30,000 rows per second. But on `insert into ...` I only get < 1000 inserts per second.

Is this (factor) what I should expect. (I actually expected a comparable speed on the insert part.)

Comment: select * is a read operation, even for us humans reading is faster than writing something, so when you are doing `insert into select * from` you are reading and writing data at the same time, expecting slower reponse when you are doing more stuff it is pretty much expected.

Comment: Your select * might have all the data in cache (you can check with "set statistics io on") and then it's just a memory operation vs. insert that always writes to disc.

Comment: Yep. I anticipated insert to be slower but not by that factor. Is my expectation wrong or is something wrong with my system or my usage of it.

Comment: Insert is expensive in RDBMS, depending on your RDBMS there are ways to trade consistency by speed, you may configure your database to write faster by not flushing to disk but if something odd happens you'll may (and most sure will) loose data.

Answer (score 0):

Insert speed varies wildly by the method of inserting. There is a disk and a CPU component. From the low speed of inserting I guess that that you are inserting rows one by one in a separate transaction each. This pretty much maximizes CPU and disk usage. Each insert is a write to disk.

Make yourself familiar with efficient ways of inserting. There are plenty with various degrees of performance and development time required to program them.

To get you started with something simple: Enclose many (100+) inserts in one transaction. Insert in batches.

Comment: To add on to this answer, when each insert is executed as an individual transaction, the speed constraint is the synchronous transaction log IO necessary to guarantee transaction durability during commit.  Batching multiple inserts in a larger transaction or using a bulk insert method will mitigate the performance hit.  Also consider that individual inserts require separate round trips whereas many rows are streamed with a single `SELECT`.